# How to Fetch a data with particular percentage in each category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

1. I have a Mysql table named 'Quiz' and the columns 'question',
   'answer',    and 'category'.
2. I have a Math, Physic and Chemistry category, and 10 questions in each one of them.
3. If my query is  `mysql select * from Quiz` , I need to print something like
   `'mysql select * from Quiz  where category = maths %50, physics %20
   and chemistry %30`

   How could it be done in a Mysql query? Please help me

Comment: so you want 150% of the results in the table?

Comment: Sorry i meant 100% result with a particular percentage in particular category

Comment: can you give us some example data and expected results to make this clearer

Comment: I think what he means is, I am going to make a test with 10 questions randomly, 3 from chemistry, 2 from physics and 5 from maths category (but I'm not sure), tbh I don't actually think this is it, it would be strange to want to do this

Comment: @ jeremy c. exactly u meant that. Thats what i need. that 3 from chemistry, 2 from physics and 5 from maths will value may be change

Comment: you might want to write this code in php rather than using mysql, read all ids from each category in an array, create a random generator that will get the object in index 'random' from the array and run that code through a for loop for how many you need, there is no get random in sql

Comment: SekarG update your question accordingly, sample data and a desired result (or in this case several sample results) also useful.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "need to print"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done only by separate `SELECTs`. But you can combine them into single one using `UNION`.

```
(select * from Quiz where category='math' order by rand() limit 5)
union all
(select * from Quiz where category='physics' order by rand() limit 3)
union all
(select * from Quiz where category='chemistry' order by rand() limit 2)
```

You should pre-calculate amount of questions for each category.
Also note, ordering by `rand()` is a bad manner for big tables.

Comment: It's good practice to do UNION ALL instead of just UNION as long as there are no explicit choice to remove duplicated rows.

Comment: This works great. But i have 1000 number of questions how can i used rand(); Can you suggest any other functions similar to rand();

Comment: @jarlh, I suspect there should be no duplicate rows in different categories :) Anyway, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Sekar.G, 1000 rows is not too much :) But if you're interesting, just search *how to select random rows without ordering by rand()*

Comment: OK thank you, How could set my limit by Percentage not in number.

Comment: You can't limit by percentage, only by pre-calculated number. `number = round(total_questions_count * percentage / 100)`, where `percentage` is a number 0..100